# Using VMs as pods in Kubernetes

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, kubernetes

I have found [KubeVirt.io](https://kubevirt.io/) project which allows you to manage VM as if being Pods in Kubernetes cluster. The problem with that is it is using KVM to create such VMs on the nodepool nodes. Is there any alternative that will create VM directly as Azure VM? I have read about [Metal3.io](https://metal3.io/), but not sure how they fit in the picture.

Comment: Be aware it is very likely creating them via KVM in order to influence their networking, since kubernetes networking model is that _all_ Pods can reach each other and their Services route to all matching Pods, which isn't something it can easily influence just with Azure networking by itself. I mean, _possible_, sure, but demonstrably hard in the general case. Are you sure you don't have an XY problem?

Comment: Sure Kubevirt.io is using another level of virtualization for VM creation, but we have for example Virtual nodes which are running pods as Azure container instances. I think that it can be done.